# Why lambda function does not apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this data frame depicted in the picture:
[image]

I wanted to fill in nan values in the Date column and wrote the following code:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].apply(lambda d: '1' if d==np.nan else d)
```

but it does not work for me. I totally got confused.

Comment: What's the datatype of that column?  `np.nan` only works if it is a floating-point column.  Pandas has an `isna` function for checking for NaNs.

Comment: Use `is` to compare `np.nan`s:  `np.nan == np.nan` <- this is False `np.nan is np.nan` <- this is True.

Comment: Don't compare `np.nan` with `==`. Use `pd.isnull(d)` instead.

Comment: Note that it is part of the IEEE standard that nan != nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing it in 1 of these 3 ways

for all nan

```py
df.fillna('1', inplace=True)
```

for specific col

```py
df["Date"] = df["Date"].fillna('1')
```

```py
df.Date = df.Date.fillna('1')
```

with lambda function

```py
df['Date']=df['Date'].apply(lambda d: '1' if pd.isnull(d) else d)
```

to set the value based on month or day columns requires access to those columns, as well as the row the current null is at. This means you probably don't want to apply the changes in a .apply on the "date" col specifically

Instead, get the na mask for that col, and apply the change to the "date" col based on that

```py
import pandas as pd

df = {
    "Date": ["2020-02-12", None, "2020-04-12"],
    "Month": ["Feb", "March", "April"]    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print('df before set: \n',df)
# get na 
date_is_null = (df["Date"].isna())

# apply dynamic value to null depending on value in another column
df.loc[date_is_null, 'Date']=df.loc[date_is_null, "Month"]
print('df after set: \n',df)
```

output

```
df before set: 
          Date  Month
0  2020-02-12    Feb
1        None  March
2  2020-04-12  April
df after set: 
          Date  Month
0  2020-02-12    Feb
1       March  March
2  2020-04-12  April
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. I need to fill the null values with specific values for each of them. Thus, I decided to use lambda function.

Comment: @SikSik what do you mean by "specific values for each of them". is each subsequent na date supposed to increase the number it's set to? your lambda makes the intent look like you want to set all na's in the Date col to "1". either of the last 2 options will do that

Comment: I just wanted to show my way of using lambda function. In fact I will fill the null values of the Date column by making use of values of Month and Day_Name.

Comment: @SikSik update my answer to include a way to dynamically set the replacement for null's based on the value in a different column on the null row

Comment: Thanks, it was a wise answer. Moreover, I can do arithmetic operations among columns and this makes your answer very fit to my problem.